# Complete the Pointer Set

Tags: knowledge, pattern

The following items all have something in common.

> - A Scandinavian country.
> - A manual consisting of aphorisms.
> - A famous former English professional footballer.
> - Beef or mutton fat.
> - A genus of evergreen trees.
> - A former chemical symbol.

Moreover, with the addition of one more item they would form a complete set, which I call a **pointer set.**

**Can you determine what the items above have in common?**
**Can you give an example of an item which would complete the set?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A Scandinavian country. (credit @Weathervane)

> Sweden - adding day anagrams to Wednesday

A manual consisting of aphorisms. (credit @Weathervane)

> sutra  - adding day anagrams to Saturday

A famous former English professional footballer.

> Hurst → Thursday

Beef or mutton fat. (credit @Weathervane)

> suet - Tuesday

A genus of evergreen trees.

> fir - Friday

A former chemical symbol.

> Uns (Unnilseptium [107] the temporary name given to bohrium) → Sunday

Can you determine what the items above have in common?

> Adding *day*, they anagram to the days of the week. Credit to **AHKieran** here, as originally just had the answers contain the three letter day abbreviations.

Can you give an example of an item which would complete the set?

> Vietnamese salad → Nom and day anagram to Monday.

Comment: Good spot: my second attempt was trying to make rot13(pbzcnff cbvagf) but there aren't enough options.

Comment: I think the final answer should be: rot13(Gurl ner nyy nantenzf bs gur Qnl fhssvkrf (r.t. Fjrqra => Jrqarf+qnl) Naq gur svany cneg bs gur frg jbhyq or ZBA, jvgu na nccebcevngr pyhr orvat "Babzngbcbrvp fbhaq sbe rngvat")

Comment: whoops chose the wrong box to copy in rot13 xD

Comment: @AHKieran - you're right - that's more specific,  you could answer.

Comment: Nicely done Tom and yes, AHKieran's suggestion is correct.

Comment: Thanks AHKieran for the complete solution and hexomino for the puzzle. Still haven't explained the title.

Comment: I'll give you a pass with the title as it's not essential for the problem nor is it particularly illuminating.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my attempt to answer the first part, not quite right, maybe not at all right!

A Scandinavian country.

> **Sw**eden

A manual consisting of aphorisms.

> **Su**tra

A famous former English professional footballer.

> **Su**lzeer Jeremiah Campbell

Beef or mutton fat.

> **Su**et

A genus of evergreen trees.

> T**su**ga

A former chemical symbol.

> **Su** for sulphur or sulfur. It is now **S** and I can't find anything to support the idea that it changed.

---

The common theme of these is

> A syllable spelled or pronounced **su**.

I don't know why another example could *complete the set.*

Comment: Some of your guesses are correct but the pattern is not (although it's interesting that you found such a connection). Have a look at your answers again and see if you can see anything that could link some of them.

Comment: I've been struggling with research to justify the last one, or something very similar like rot13(fhycungr vba). Should I give up on that avenue?

Comment: Yes, it's not something that is very obscure.

Comment: I believe the beef or mutton fat is rot13(gnyybj).

Comment: I think the aphorisms manual could also be rot13(nyznanp)

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof that was one of my options until I spotted the (false) connection.